# setAttribute no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tardes, quiero poner un código que me desactive un input cuando tengo otro activo. En estos momentos tengo esto y me funciona perfectamente:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
   <input type="hidden" id='name' name='name' class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>"/>
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
     <input type="radio" name="bd" value="op1" checked id="op1" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">Op1
     </label>
     <label>
     <input type="radio" name="bd" value="op2" id="op2" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">Op2
     </label>
     <label>
     <input type="radio" name="bd" value="examenes"  id="examenes" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">Op3
     </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
   <div class="col-sm-5">
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label class="control-label">Tema</label>
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
<option disabled="" selected=""></option>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from categories where active = 's' order by id ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']." - ".substr($row['descripcion'], 0, 20)."..."; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Bl. 1
  
   
   Bl. 2
                                                                 
   
   Bl. 3
                                                                  
  
  Bl. 4

```
    <script>
    function houseclean() {
      if ((document.getElementById('grupo1').checked == false) && (document.getElementById('grupo2').checked == false) && (document.getElementById('grupo3').checked == false) && (document.getElementById('grupo4').checked == false)) {
        document.getElementById('category').removeAttribute('disabled');

      } else {
        category.value = "";
        document.getElementById('category').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Por ahora cuando activo cualquier checkbox "grupo" me desactiva el input "category" y viceversa. Hasta ahí bien pero lo que quiero hacer es que cuando le de a la tercera opción del input radio "examenes" me desactive y borre los checkbox "grupo" y "category". También lo contrario me gustaría, que si hago algun check en "grupo" o pongo algun tema en "category" me borre y desactive la tercera opción de radio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar la misma lógica de usar el atributo `checked` como lo hiciste en tus checkbox, solo agrega un nuevo bloque `if{...}else{...}` donde captures el valor de tu radio y en base a si esté o no checkeado haces tus funciones de ocultar los checkbox y el select categoría:

```js
function houseclean() {
  if (document.getElementById('examenes').checked == true) {
    var select = document.getElementById('category');
    select.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    select.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0]
      .style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else {
    var select = document.getElementById('category');
    select.style.visibility = 'visible';
    select.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0]
      .style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  if (
    (document.getElementById('grupo1').checked == false) &&
    (document.getElementById('grupo2').checked == false) &&
    (document.getElementById('grupo3').checked == false) &&
    (document.getElementById('grupo4').checked == false)
  ) {
    document.getElementById('category')
      .removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    category.value = "";
    document.getElementById('category')
      .setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <input type="hidden" id='name' name='name' class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>" />
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
                 <input type="radio" name="bd" value="questions" checked id="questions" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">
                Op1
             </label>
      <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="bd" value="meta2016" id="op2" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">
                                                        Op2
                 </label>
      <label>
             <input type="radio" name="bd" value="examenes"  id="examenes" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">
                                                        Op3
              </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Tema</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                                                        <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
                                                        <?php
                                                        $query = mysql_query("select * from categories where active = 's' order by id ASC");
                                                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

                                                        ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']." - ".substr($row['descripcion'], 0, 20)."..."; ?></option>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" id="grupo1" name="g1" value="41" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">
                                                            Bl. 1
                                                        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="grupo2" name="g2" value="42" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">
                                                            Bl. 2
                </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="grupo3" name="g3" value="43" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">
                                                            Bl. 3
                                                        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="grupo4" name="g4" value="44" onClick="javascript:houseclean();">
                                                            Bl. 4
                                                        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Me funciona perfecto. Mil millones de gracias... solo una tontería... para que no se vea la palabra Tema del label?? se puede hacer igualmente??

Comment: Si, agrega `document.getElementsByClassName('control-label').style.visibility = 'hidden'` y lo mismo para `visibility = 'visible'`

Comment: Aprovechándome un poco más y pidiendote disculpas... cómo haría para que si cualquier radio no este checked no me deje darle a submit???